# Сделать один список длинною другого

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Два списка,

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
b = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Каким образом возможно сделать список b = длинны списка a, чтобы

```
b = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Сначала повторим список столько раз, сколько он полностью "влезет" в `a`, а потом добавим к этому остаток - срез массива длиной остатка от деления длины списка `b` на длину списка `a`:

```
b = b * (len(a) // len(b)) + b[:len(a) % len(b)]
```

Comment: то что мне было и нужно, использовать itertools не хотел

Answer (score 4):

Я рекомендую использовать вот такой вариант. Он обладает большей ясностью, по сравнению с тем вариантом, который уже привели до меня - здесь практически с первого взгляда понятно, что происходит.

Вообще, при манипуляциях со списками, list comprehension и модуль itertools - это первое, что должно прийти в голову.

```
from itertools import cycle

b_cycle = cycle(b)

new_b = [next(b_cycle) for _ in a]
```

Answer (score 2):

Лучще вариант это исползуя [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) и [`itertools.islice`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice)

```
In [63]: import itertools

In [64]: a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

In [65]: b = ['a', 'b', 'c']

In [66]: list(itertools.islice(itertools.cycle(b), len(a)))
Out[66]: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a']
```

Можно это делать с `zip` и `cycle`

```
In [67]: c, _ = zip(*zip(itertools.cycle(b), a))

In [68]: c
Out[68]: ('a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in b:
    if len(b)!=len(a):
        b.append(i)
```

Comment: Вы тут подразумеваете, что на входе `b` короче, чем `a`. А что, если будет наоборот? Вы же не проверяете этого условия.